# Require 1 of 2 arguments in a method / function (one of two arguments optional)

Tags: php, methods, arguments

I have a method / function (in a class) that I am calling and I want to pass either and id or a url. The method then uses one of these arguments in a mysql WHERE query. It can only use one or the other.

How can I require one of two arguments? Or in other words how can I only make one of two arguments optional?

Is there a better way than to just make both arguments optional and use several if else statements?

Comment: How about simulating named parameters (with taking an associative array as param) instead?

Comment: function x($param1, $param2 = null){ if ($param2 != null){ ... }else{ ... }}

Comment: array method would still require if else statements if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Seth this method would not allow only $param2 to be passed.

Comment: @DominicM well if you think about it there is no way for one method to know wich argument you passed to it (if both were optional, but at the same time one mandatory)

Comment: @mmmshuddup please un-delete your answer, I think it was actually the best solution.

Comment: @DominicM Sorry I _just_ noticed this.  I was reluctant to undelete my answer after everything, but I did anyway per your request.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to literally *require* an argument:

```
public function fetchRow($where)
{
    if (empty($where['id']) && empty($where['url'])) {
        throw new Exception('WHERE clause must be supplied');
    }

    // proxy to specific method
    if (!empty($where['id'])) {
        return $this->fetchById((int) $where['id']);
    } elseif (!empty($url)) {
        return $this->fetchByUrl((string) $where['url']);
    }
}

public function fetchById($id) 
{
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?')) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        // ...
    }
}

// ...
$object = new MyClass();
try {
    $object->fetchRow(); // would throw exception
    $object->fetchRow(array('id' => 10)); // would work
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // do something, for example:
    echo $ex->getMessage(); // echoes 'at least one argument must be supplied'
}
```

Comment: In your case, calling `$object->myFunction(false)` would also throw an exception.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I think you're nitpicking, this was a simple _example_. Or do you expect me to write his entire application? Geez

Comment: Well, also in your case, **both $arg1 and $arg2 are already required**. And, on top of that, ***this doesn't even answer the question's requirements***, since he wants to have one or the other. So please excuse me if my vote still stands.

Comment: I dont entirely understand this example (I'm new to oop) but I don't see how this can work. I would still only be able to pass either requiredArg or both but not ONLY optionalArg.

Comment: I was demonstrating the method I use when I want to _require_ an argument(s).  "Exception handling is the process of responding to the occurrence, during computation, of exceptions..."  Exception might arguably be synonymous with "errors."  But they are different in nature.  `try {} catch() {}` is used to avoid `Fatal Error: Uncaught exception`.

Comment: @mmmshuddup: I'd have to disagree with that definition. Exceptions are reserved for "Exceptional events", i.e. events which **shouldn't** happen, but **could** happen. A database connection fail, a file not found error, invalid arguments, etc. We're talking about a state where you expect exactly one argument to be passed, be it the first or the second. So in your case, it's very possible that the first argument is left out (and it's also valid!). So I think your Exception is misplaced.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha take that up with wikipedia then, it wasn't _my_ definition.  I know what exceptions are, and I agree with your explanation.  I just don't see how the definition I provided says otherwise, nor my example.  For eff sakes just delete my answer. I'm sick of this.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used a very simple method which resulted in no code duplication and actually will allow for many more arguments to be passed in the future if needed without changes to the method.

```
public function getMovie($argType, $arg) {
    $movieQuery =  "SELECT 
        id, rt_id, imdb_id, url, rt_url, type, adult, 
        DATE_FORMAT(release_date, '%Y') AS year, date_added,
        title, runtime, budget, revenue, homepage, rating,
        tagline, overview, popularity, image, backdrop, trailer
        FROM movies
        WHERE " . $argType . " =  ?";

    $movieResult = $this->_query($movieQuery, $arg);
    $movies      = array();

    if ($movieResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        while ($m = $movieResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $movies[] = array(
                'title'        => $m['title'],
                'duplicate'    => $m['duplicate'],
                'url'          => $m['url'],
                'rt_url'       => $m['rt_url'],
                'release_date' => $m['release_date'],
                'date_added'   => $m['date_added'],
                'type'         => 'movie',
                'adult'        => $m['adult'],
                'id'           => $id,
                'rt_id'        => $m['rt_id'],
                'imdb_id'      => $m['imdb_id'],
                'rating'       => $m['rating'],
                'tagline'      => $m['tagline'],
                'overview'     => $m['overview'],
                'popularity'   => $m['popularity'],
                'runtime'      => $m['runtime'],
                'budget'       => $m['budget'],
                'revenue'      => $m['revenue'],
                'homepage'     => $m['homepage'],
                'image'        => $m['image'],
                'backdrop'     => $m['backdrop'],
                'trailer'      => $m['trailer'] 
            );
        }
        return $movies;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is good in that it works, but you should really use `bind_param` with prepared statements.  :)

Comment: What's a bind param? / prepared statements? I am planning to use database class in the future so the query woun't actually be in this method.

Comment: My example assumed a db class for the sake of simplicity and uses the `bind_param` function.  But here is a great source for learning about prepared statements (they are the most secure besides stored procedures). http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: link bookmarked until performance is an issue (little over my head for now). Other than exceptions, and bind param usage in your answer my method is good right? I mean it's simpler in a way since I wount need to create $where parameter before passing it to the method when calling... your way seems to have more if / else statements than if you passed 2 arguments instead of $where array.

Comment: Yes, besides that stuff, the logic is great for novice in my humble opinion.  Don't get intimidated by difficult-to-understand articles though.  Just read it slowly and read it multiple times, you'll get it!  By the way, I partially edited your answer to use the `?` in place of `$arg` and then I also instead passed `$arg` to the `$this->_query()` function so you could do your binding _there_.  :)

Comment: Here is another great article on prepared statements: http://devzone.zend.com/239/ext-mysqli-part-i_overview-and-prepared-statements/

Comment: Ahh, now I get the "?" it's kind of a place-holder for binding right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19730/discussion-between-mmmshuddup-and-dominicm)

Answer (score 0):

If it can only use one or the other, then you have state. If you have state, you need polymorphism, or in this very small use-case, two different methods.

```
public function getById($id) {}
public function getByUrl($url) {}
```

That's the end of it. That's the best you can do for yourself.

**if and only if** you don't know in advance which is being passed in, (like the case of user input), you can make a *third* method, to parse and validate the input string, determine which type it is, and call the appropriate method.

Comment: Part of the point of getById is to validate the $id to be an ID. You can't do that reasonably if you mix the two methods together...

Comment: I was not nitpicking, your approach is fundamentally flawed from the bottom, it's not some small error that can be ignored, you completely disregarded the question, and answered solely based on the (slightly misleading) title!

Comment: Not entirely, but I can see how you'd think that.  I edited my answer none the less.

Comment: God, I hate naruto so badly, but must agree with him this time

Comment: @Seth: I hate Naruto too. He ruined my plans for world *peace*. I just want my pet inside him, and I'll be off to my marry way.

Comment: This does seem like the best solution, could you elaborate on the  polymorphism method? Also what about checking weather argument is a string (url) or int (id)?

Comment: @DominicM: PHP doesn't allow typehinting for primitive values (such as int), so you'll have to check those on your own (`is_int()` or `is_numeric()` for example). As for polymorphism, it's a way of splitting similar (usually state based) functionality into different types of object, all extending the same base object. For example, I have an `abstract class Shape`, and `class Circle extends Shape` and `class Square extends Shape`. There's a method on the Shape object, `getNumberOfCorners()`, Each concrete class would then override (Circle returning 0, and Square returning 4).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha that's not true of PHP not allowing type hinting of _any_ primitive data types.  Unless you don't consider `array`, for example, to be primitive.  `function functionName(array $arg1)` works

Comment: @mmmshuddup: array isn't a primitive. The primitives are: int (long), boolean, float (double), string, char. And none of those are allowed. `array` isn't a primitive per-se and its addition to the allowed typehints was added recently.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I guess `array` has been around for so long that it _feels_ like it should be "primitive."  But yeah.

Comment: $Madara Uchiha thinking bit more this doesn't seem such a good solution any more, how could I avoid code duplications? Since it only a single argument would be different in these two methods and all of the code exactly the same...

Comment: @DominicM my solution should still work for you, however I deleted it as I could not put up with the trolling anymore. If you'd like I can give you a pastie.  You don't _have_ to use `Exception`s, it was just a friendly suggestion.  You can simply use `if` if you really want. Focusing too much on design as a novice will only frustrate you.  Good design comes with experience among other things, for now do what you can to follow best practices but don't get _hung up_ on them.  There is something to be said about just getting the job done!

Comment: @mmmshuddup well said, I found a super simple way to solve my problem, will probably answer my own question since  most other answers are now deleted :) Thanks!

Comment: @DominicM You're welcome!  Happy to help :)  I am curious to see what you come up with, so yes please post your answer when you're ready!